# Reading value from matlab function in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, word-wrap

I have matlab wrapped .dll file and want to display a value from a function in it.

My code looks like

```
plotting plot= new plotting();
double a=1;
doubleb=2.2;
object x=plotting.plotMe(a,b);
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

It displays z=3.2 which is returned by matlab function as a+b and my `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())` returns `System.Double[,]`. I want to keep to value of z and use it later on my code somehow.

matlab function is defined as follow:

```
object[] plotting.plotMe(int numArgsOut,object a,object b)
```

I would appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

If plotting.plotMe() is going to reliably return the same format, a simple solution would be to take the part of the string after the equals sign and parse it. Could be done by finding the index of the equals sign, or splitting the string, or however. Something like

```
String numString = x.ToString().Split('=')[1]; // (1) because we want the piece to the right
double num = Double.Parse(numString);
```

should work.

Comment: thank you for your reply. It gives an exception and says "Index was outside the bounds of the array" at String numString = x.ToString().Split('=')[1];

Comment: If that's the case, then (on this run), x.ToString() didn't have an equals sign in it. Try it again but have it print x.ToString() before the split.